# Accessed non-system Files and Directory by Google Chrome

Tags: linux, filesystems, chrome

Hello how can I get detect the which non-system file or directory accessed by Google Chrome on Linux?

Comment: What does "non-system file" mean? There's really no such distinction in Linux, so you're going to have to define it.

Comment: I mean user's personal files, for example when google chrome read the user's personal files (after user granted the access) how can I understand it whether they are accessed by the Chrome?